# Does django orm create objects instantly

Tags: django, celery, django-orm

I have a a django view which adds object id's to a queue via an API POST request. I then have a celery task which dequeues the id and does some processing. Sometimes the celery task throws an error indicating the object does not exists. I added a a 5 second delay to the view and I don't get that error anymore.

```
View:
def create(self, request):
    user = request.user
    serializer = UnpredictedSentenceSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        saved_raw_text = UnpredictedSentence.objects.create(
                                    raw_text=serializer.data['raw_text'],
                                    user=user)
        prediction.apply_async(
            args=[saved_raw_text.pk],
            countdown=5
        )
        print(saved_raw_text.pk)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(
                    serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


Task:
@task()
def prediction(id):
    print(id)
    print(type(id))
    UnpredictedSentence.objects.get(pk=id)
    try:
       un_sent = UnpredictedSentence.objects.get(pk=id)
    except UnpredictedSentence.DoesNotExist:
       un_sent = None
    if un_sent:
       print(type(un_sent.raw_text))
       text = json.loads(un_sent.raw_text)
       results = kudos.main(text['raw_text'])
       PredictedSentence.objects.create(
         cleaned_text=results['cleaned_text'],
         raw_text=results['raw_text'],
         sentiment=results['sentiment'],
         user=un_sent.user)
       print(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly a transaction issue. Because of transaction isolation, other processes won't see objects that have been created until the transaction is committed, which happens at the end of the request. The five-second delay gives enough time for this to happen.

Comment: Just a general comment in addition, using sleeps to solve race conditions is almost always a bad idea. Can the celery task do a check to see if it exists, and if not, leave it in the queue for another worker to pick up?